# License upgrade - retake required?

Tags: united-states, license

It's been more than a year since I passed my Technician and General exams and obtained my license. If I were now to go for my Extra class license, would it simply be a matter of taking and passing the Extra exam, or would I need to pass the previous exams again? Under what circumstances is it necessary to "start from the beginning" in terms of testing?

I am in particular interested in the rules for the United States, but a broader treatment would certainly be more generally useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can bring proof of having passed Element 3 (the General class exam), such as your paper license or a Successful Completion of Examination (CSCE) you will only have to take Element 4 (the Extra class exam).

Comment: To clarify, the license alone is sufficient? No CSCE is required if you have the license?

Comment: @KD8TGR Yes, but you'll have to take the paper license the FCC sent you as proof.

Comment: Take a copy of your license long with the original. a copy must be part of the application and most VE teams do not have access to copier during testing.

Answer (score 3):

You will not need to test for anything you have been licensed for again -- as long as your license is not expired or still in the grace period. At the previous exam, you were issued a white slip of paper called a CSCE (Certificate of Successful Completion of Exam). CSCEs are good for one year. To apply the credit of either your license or an unexpired CSCE, you will need to bring the original document and a copy. The examiners will review the original, and submit the copy with your application.

See http://www.arrl.org/what-to-bring-to-an-exam-session

Good luck with your Amateur Extra exam.