# Testing requirements for 5 year old tech license to take general exam

Tags: united-states, license

Will I need to take the Technician exam again when I test for General if my Technician license is over 4 years old?

Answer (score 3):

If you got your license after March 21, 1987, then when applying for General you do not need to take the Technician examination again.

The relevant regulation is [§97.505](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c89c6646e415ced62cde7df69e8f017a&mc=true&node=se47.5.97_1505&rgn=div8), which says

> The administering VEs must give credit as specified below to an examinee holding any of the following license grants:

which is followed by a table specifying that if you hold “Technician Plus; or Technician granted on or after March 21, 1987”, then you get credit for Element 2, which is the formal name for the Technician exam.

Comment: It's also worth reminding that the asker can generally sit for US General and Extra at the same session and get it all out of the way for good.  See also: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/610/license-upgrade-retake-required?rq=1, with the reminder to bring your existing license with you.  Always best to check with the VE's to let them know and make sure you have what you need, and so do they...

Answer (score 2):

You will get credit for Element 2 as long as your license is valid.

Bring a copy of your existing license that we can keep. Volunteer Examiners conducting testing sessions usually do not have access to copiers and we have to include a copy of your license in the paperwork we turn in after the exam session.

You can take element 3 for General and if you pass that you can opt to take Element 4 for Extra.

You might also want to let them know ahead of time you are trying to upgrade from Technician. It takes 3 VE to conduct a testing session, for General and Extra, the VEs must be Extras. For Technician they can be Generals. While most VE are Extras, there are are few General VEs who can only give Element 2 tests for Technicians.